# Unserialize function in xCode

Tags: xcode

Im new to Xcode and object programming. In my app i load a JSON file that contains a object called: custom_fields. The value for custom_fiels is a php string like:

( "a:4:{s:11:\"ebbersmedia\";s:8:\"ebb_true\";s:10:\"uitlichten\";s:15:\"uitlichten_true\";s:12:\"image01\";s:71:\"http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/image_01.png\";s:6:\"image02\";s:66:\"http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/image_02.jpg\";}" );

In php i can use the function unserialize to create a array. How can i do this in xCode? I only need the image URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I use JSONKit for this purpose: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

It's as simple as this:

```
NSDictionary* jsonObjects = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
```

`jsonObjects` is an NSDictionary where the keys are the JSON keys and the values are, of course, the JSON values. It makes a good attempt at making those values the right type, too.